# create chatter post upon a field change

Tags: workflow, chatter, process-builder, publisher-action

I have created a a quickAction on Case object, called "Escalate". Apart from filling in some custom fields on case, it checks the "isEscalated" field and changes Status of the case to "Escalated"

Goal - When the status changes to "Escalated", i want to post a chatter on the case with @mention to user's manager.

I just need to know how many ways are there to do this (with as well as without apex). Just pointing in general direction is good, i can do the digging myself. I just want to make sure i dont miss some possible solution.

i think process builder can do this (and if i am wrong, please let me know)
Will workflow do that (let post chatter)? I will look at documentation. But if anyone wants to give a yes or no answer, it will help

Apart from above two ways, what other ways are there?

UPDATE
I realize that workflows are useless for this.
I tried using process builder, but i have two concerns-
1) Need to @mention Running user's manager. Can't seem to find an option for Running User in process builder. Does anyone know a solution for this.
2) In the body of the comment, i need to display a numeric field, if it has a number, otherwise, display 0. So this requires use of formula. I can't seem to get it working in process builder. I need something like this in the chatter -

```
Balance Due : {!NullValue(Case.Balance_Due__c, "0")}.
```

Any possible solutions to above 2 issues with process builder? Or should i start looking at apex (hopefully we can pass current user and current case record to an apex class from process builder)

Comment: Workflow rules actually can't create chatter posts. The process builder should work for you though.

Comment: You can refer this....http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=http://automationchampion.com/2014/05/12/preschedule-chatter-posts/&ei=Emsw4cu9&lc=en-IN&s=1&m=253&ts=1452661130&sig=ALL1Aj6xWi3C1cBdqq9ZMnFjzCfKnyjpJw

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is via Process Builder.  There is a Post to Chatter action!  So simple and easy to use... just set your criteria (when a case is changed to escalated) and then set the action after that happens.

Other options are to trigger a Flow from Process Builder to do the post (that doesn't really make too much sense unless you're doing queries to fill in the information or find who you should mention).  And lastly is of course Apex.

Comment: David, please read my update. I do need to @mention current user's manager.

And in the body of chatter, i need some formula to display value of a field conditionally.

Anyway it can be done via process builder? Or should i think about apex

Comment: Yes --- see my update, I'll add in a screenshot.  You can add in all merge fields you want -- I like to use a formula on the record and then reference that in PB as opposed to doing it in PB if I can.

Comment: Scratch that... as I tested it doesn't work dynamically in PB :( -- I would try the Apex route cause Flow's @mentions aren't very functional.

Comment: An update, you can dynamically mention in process builder: @[Field Id Merge Field Here]  (Make sure you have the outer brackets).